# how convert string to xml for using in createUnmarshaller for convert to pojo Entity

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to convert a string to xml and then use the createUnmarshaller method to convert to pojo entity.

xmlString:

```
 <File>
     <code>63213713</code>
     <name>textsss</name>
     <player>GAMMER</player>
     <system>SS</system>
  <File>
```

My Method convert String to Xml:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Source src = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Use String reader
        Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );


        src = new DOMSource( document );
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("./src/main/folder/xmlFile.xml"));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(src, result);
```

I Have method Marshaller:

```
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("br.com.Test.domain");
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Object obj = um.unmarshal();
```

How to convert String to xml and using this method Marshaller?i don't understand how to pass a result of method conversion for method unmarshaller.
What kind should I go through? a Source?

Comment: Which string? Which xml? Very unclear. XML is a text-based format. So if you have a string containing an XML document, there is nothing to convert. Or are you asking how to convert a String to one of the types accepted as argument by unmarshal()? Like a Reader? StringReader is a Reader reading from a String. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html

Comment: @JBNizet a updated a post. i place my method convert string to xml, i dont understand how to pass conversion for unmarshaller.

Comment: @joeyanthon you don't need to do anything fancy. Just do `StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString );` and then call `unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);`